# how to fire findoneandupdate query in mongo db to update array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update a field of the array object.
I want to update field of    `_idWorksInRestaurant` for experience[0].

here is my json object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "_idUserProfile" : NumberInt(1), 
    "experience" : [
    {
        "fromDate" : "06/2017", 
        "zip" : "95014", 
        "restaurantType" : "Family Style", 
        "_idWorksInRestaurant" : "8020", 

    }, 
    {
        "fromDate" : "11/2017", 
        "restaurantType" : "Ethnic", 
        "_idWorksInRestaurant" : "-1",

    }], 

"__v" : NumberInt(0)
```

Here is my code: In bari variable I am passing index no

```
var t = "experience." + bari + ".$._idWorksInRestaurant";
var z = "experience."+bari+"._idWorksInRestaurant";
ModelBarTender.findOneAndUpdate({ _idUserProfile: user._id, z: req.body.experience[bari]._idWorksInRestaurant },
    {
         $set: { t: restoid },
         $new: true, upsert: true
    },
    function (err, bartender) {
        if (!err) {
             bari++;
             bartenderexp(exp, req, imageURL, i9form, bari, callback);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: can you show your request body?

Comment: also, can you try findOneAndUpdate({ _idUserProfile: user._id, : "experience._idWorksInRestaurant":req.body.experience[bari]._idWorksInRestaurant },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var updateObj = {$set:{}};
updateObj.$set["experience." + bari + "._idWorksInRestaurant"] = restoid;
ModelBarTender.findOneAndUpdate({
    _idUserProfile: user._id
}, updateObj, {
    new: true, upsert: false
}, function (err, bartender) {
    if (!err) {
        bari++;
        bartenderexp(exp, req, imageURL, i9form, bari, callback);
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)